# ios public static const equiv

Tags: ios, static, constants, public, extern

I'm trying to accomplish a C style version of `public` `static` `const`

What I tried doing already:

ClassA.h

- `extern const int FEATURES;`

ClassA.m

- `#define THE_CONST 123`

ClassB.b

- `#import ClassA.h`
- `initWithFrame`

  - `FEATURES`

Xcode does not through a runtime error, but rather a build error of `undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_THE_CONST", referenced from: ...`

How can I share an `extern` `const` to for another class to use as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ClassA.h

- `extern const int FEATURES;`

ClassA.m

- `const int FEATURES = <your const value here>;`